# Get child node value from xml which have single attributes

Tags: c#, xml

Hi all i am getting an `XML` format as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
    <Response ID="xyx66860512" PID="13681839" ERROR="0" STATUS="5"/>
</Root>
```

from this i would like to get `ID, PID, Error, and Status` how can i get these values from the XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Linq-Xml you can do the following:

```
var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<Root>
    <Response ID=""xyx66860512"" PID=""13681839"" ERROR=""0"" STATUS=""5""/>
</Root>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var element = doc.Root.Element("Response");
var id = element.Attribute("ID").Value;
var pid = Int32.Parse(element.Attribute("PID").Value);
var error = element.Attribute("ERROR").Value;
var status = element.Attribute("STATUS").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your XML technology. 
If you are using Linq-to-XML:

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse([your xml]);
string ID = (string)root.Element("Response").Attribute("ID");
etc...
```